# Wordpress Site and WP-Admin blank

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress install is now blank and showing no errors. I removed all plugins, no dice. Removed theme, no dice. Checked the functions.php file and nothing was wrong. Anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: What recent changes have been made to the install? Did you update WP Core? Did you modify your htaccess? Need a little more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awful question, far too vague.  If you want a real answer, provide details.

Did you move the site?  Does the site URL stored within WP differ from the domain you're using to access it?  Did you edit core (in which I say: WHY!)? OR wp-config.php and forget a closing bracket or a semi-colon?  There's way too many reasons your site could be down...first and foremost, turn your errors on (via functions.php) and go from there

`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`

& also go to wp-config and add: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. However, showing the error did work. Was able to nail down the issue and remove the problem code. Thanks!