# WordPress site transfer to new server and wp-admin dashboard doesn't show anything after logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have transfer my website ( **WordPress** ) old server to new server by uploading backup files.

Website shows everything fine but when I logged in through `wp-admin` 
it shows blank page.

I got this error information from `error_log` file

Here is the error message.

```
PHP Fatal error:  

Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 786432 bytes) 

in `~/wp-includes/SimplePie/Item.php` on line 2736
```

This type of question asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491414/wordpress-site-and-wp-admin-blank). but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: I don't know why someone give down vote. I ask this question here because I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by uninstalling plugins.

I uninstall plugins from  `phpMyAdmin`.

Step 1: Go to wp_options table and find column `option_name` with value **`active_plugins`** click edit button.

[image]

Step 2:You have to uninstall unwanted plugins ( that causing error ) by eliminating from `option_value`

[image]

Step 3: Finally put `a:{whatever number of plugins}` to `a:0` and you can see your `wp-admin` dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase memory limit on new server!

http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit